# Can't use Xcode Simulator for Itunes Connect Screenshots

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect, xcode9

I am making an app that uses the phone's camera to identify objects and then translate them into Spanish.  I'm trying to setup the app store page and Itunes Connect says I need 5.5-inch screenshots for the page, but I don't have an iPhone plus and I can't take screenshots using the Xcode Simulator because the simulated phone doesn't have a camera, so my app's screen is blank.  What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to run app on highest resolution iPhone simulator. And later export those images using 5.5 inch width and height. Hope it helps.

You can do using any simple tool like preview on mac os

Also you can upload simple splash screen with correct resolution and update in future with correct images when you get the device

Comment: I would like to use the simulator but my app's main page is a screen showing the user's camera input using AVCpatureDevice, which does not work in the simulator.  The simulator just shows a blank screen.

Comment: do you have iphone of any size ? use that to screenshot and export to plus size. Send me screenshot, and I will do it for you

Comment: I have an iphone 6s, how would I export it to plus size? Could I just use an image resizer and resize it to the required pixel size?

Comment: If you are happy with my reply, please accept my reply